# Cannot understand pthread_cond_wait/signal/broadcast

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to understand pthread conditions.
For doing so, I wrote a very basic program but, no matter how many manuals and explanations I read, I just cannot understand how things work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
using namespace std;
#define NT 3
#define ITERATIONS 5

int countDone=0;
int a[NT] = {10, 20, 30};
pthread_cond_t doneCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t doneMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void * thread_start(void* num){
    int currIt=0;

    while(currIt < ITERATIONS){
    cout << pthread_self() << "my number is " << a[(int)num] << endl;
    a[(int)num]++;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&doneMutex);
    countDone++;

    if(countDone == NT)
        pthread_cond_signal(&doneCond);

        while(countDone != 0)
            pthread_cond_wait(&doneCond, &doneMutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&doneMutex);
    currIt++;
    }   
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t tidVec[NT];
    int i, currIt=0, ret;

    //creating threads
    for(i=0; i<NT; i++)
        pthread_create(&tidVec[i], NULL, &thread_start, (void*)i);

    while(currIt < ITERATIONS){ 
        cout << "---Iteration " << currIt << endl;  
        pthread_mutex_lock(&doneMutex);

        while(countDone < NT)
            pthread_cond_wait(&doneCond, &doneMutex);

        countDone = 0;
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&doneCond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&doneMutex);
        currIt++;
    }

    //waiting for threads termination
    for(i=0; i<NT; i++)
        pthread_join(tidVec[i], (void**)&ret);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&doneCond);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&doneMutex);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want it to do is: at each iteration, every thread prints the number assigned to itself in the array a, increments the value and then increments the counter countDone (which counts how many threads have already done their job).
The last thread that finishes its job "tells" the main the they all are done.
The main sets the counter to zero, so that a new iteration can begin.
And so on for 5 iterations.

What I get as an output is:

```
---Iteration 0
3057584960my number is 30
3065977664my number is 20
3074370368my number is 10
---Iteration 1
3057584960my number is 31
```

and then it gets stuck.
Can you please help me figure out what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: You never initialize your `pthread_mutex_t` and `pthread_cond_t` to a valid state.

Comment: You're right, I fixed, but the problem stays. Thank you for you notification anyway

Comment: In `thread_start()`, you `if(countDone == NT) pthread_cond_signal(&doneCond);` to signal the main thread. However, at that point, another thread may be waiting on `while(countDone != 0) pthread_cond_wait(&doneCond, &doneMutex);`, in which case that other thread may be woken up instead of the main thread. You could either: a) use two different `pthread_cond_t`s, or b) `pthread_cond_broadcast()` instead.

Comment: Using 2 pthread_cond_t and 2 pthread_mutex_t it works! But I had to change `while(countDone != 0)` with `if(countDone != 0)`, I hope that's correct and I just wasn't lucky :)
Thank you @EOF

Comment: Q.e.d., I was just lucky, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.
I don't know what else to do

Comment: No, checking for your predicate in a `while()`-loop is definitely correct for a `pthread_cond_wait()`. The next problem in your code is this: When the main-thread `cond_broadcast()`s, all threads waiting on the condition try to acquire the mutex. When the first thread acquires the mutex, it checks the condition and releases the mutex. But *that same thread* will soon after try to acquire the mutex *again* in its loop. If it manages to acquire the mutex before all other threads have left the `cond_wait()`, it can increment the shared variable before the other threads can check it.

Comment: Ok, I get that. I tried to avoid the problem, for example by making the main modify countDone. But in the end the very same problem just moves to another point of the code, so I'm still stuck here :(

Comment: What you are trying to do seems to have a lot of similarity with a `pthread_barrier()`. The problem you encounter is one that is discussed in the context of barriers in "The Little Book of Semaphores" by Allen B. Downey, which is free to download AFAIK.

Comment: Yes!! pthread_barrier works!! Thank you for your time, you really were helpful